# javascript string with quotes to int - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use Highcharts (Example: http://jsfiddle.net/fk3v7orz/2/), but I get the series data as string via JSON.

---

`myvar[0].data : "2,7,13,6,17,8,9,12,11,6,9,"` does not work if I change
`data: [2, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3]` to `data: [myvar[0].data]`

So how to change the string 'myvar' into int and keep the "," between them?  I'm thinking if I split by "," and make a loop to convert every one to int 
but i have no idea how to put it in date:[] after that (Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/fk3v7orz/4/)

Comment: what do you want to get with `null` values?

Comment: ah yeh i didnt notice it i change it to 0 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could split with optional whitespace and map the converted value or zero for falsy values and assing the array back to the variable.

For

```
series: [{
    name: 'Sales',
    data: data2    // no brackets, data2 is an array
}]
```

you need only the values without wrapping in another array.

```js
var data2 = "2, 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3";
   
data2 = data2.split(/,\s*/).map(v => +v || 0);

console.log(data2);
```

Comment: The `\s*` adds unnecessary complexity and why the double-check for falsy values?  The `||0` is unnecessary.

Comment: actually `'null'` is not `null`, but a string which is `NaN`. for this value, you need an explicit `0`. if you have the value `+null`, then you get zero.

Comment: True, but where was `'null'` used?  `+undefined` also would resolve to `NaN` and not `0`, but I don't know if these conditions need to be considered, since it appears as a sanitized dataset

Comment: op wants zero instead of `NaN`, as i undestand the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
 data: myvar[0].data.split(",").map(n => +n)
```

Just do what you said :)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/fk3v7orz/12/

Do what you did and make sure to assign the array to the variable you use for the data:
`data = myvar[0].data.split(",").map(n => +n)`

```js
data2 = "2, 3, null, 4, 0, 5, 1, 4, 6, 3";
data2 = data2.split(",").map(n => +n);       // <-- notice the "data2 =" 

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        options3d: {
            enabled: true,
            alpha: 10,
            beta: 25,
            depth: 70
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: '3D chart with null values'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Notice the difference between a 0 value and a null point'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            depth: 25
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: Highcharts.getOptions().lang.shortMonths,
        labels: {
            skew3d: true,
            style: {
                fontSize: '16px'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Sales',
        data: data2     // <-- notice the brackets removed
    }]
});
```

```css
#container {
    height: 400px; 
    min-width: 310px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```